# Move mouse between two monitors

Tags: autohotkey

How can I move the mouse pointer between monitors using a keyboard shortcut? I'm using autohotkey.

I didn't find a straightforward answer to it, so here's what I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach, using Ctrl+Space for this function:

```
^Space::
  CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ; This is needed to assure that you get your mouse coordinates related to the screen, not to the window 
  MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
  if( MouseX > 1920) ; 1920 is the Width of my monitor number 1, replace it with yours
  {
    MouseMove, -A_ScreenWidth, 0, 0, R
  }
  else
  {
    MouseMove, A_ScreenWidth, 0, 0, R
  }
return
```